# Connect Python3.5 (Mac OS X El Capitan) to Oracle cluster (remote)

Tags: python, oracle, macos, python-3.x, python-3.5

I am trying to connect Python3.5 (Mac OS X El Capitan) to Oracle cluster (remote).

At first I install Instant Client for x64 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html)
Then I install cx_Oracle (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/5.2.1)

For installation cx_Oracle I set:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/Applications/oracle/instantclient_11_2
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME:$PATH
```

Now I get error:

```
**Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle**
```

I don't know why it's happen. Any ideas?

I even create file **tnsnames.ora** and put it to `/Applications/oracle/instantclient_11_2/network/admin/tnsnames.ora`

```
orcl=
 (description=
   (address_list=
     (address = (protocol = TCP)(host = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(port = 1521))
   )
 (connect_data =
   (service_name=oratst)
 )
)
```

My python code:

```
import traceback
import os

os.environ["ORACLE_HOME"] = "/Applications/oracle/instantclient_11_2"
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "/Applications/oracle/instantclient_11_2"
os.environ["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "/Applications/oracle/instantclient_11_2"
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "/Applications/oracle/instantclient_11_2"

import cx_Oracle
try:
    connection = cx_Oracle.Connection('user', 'password', cx_Oracle.makedsn('remote_ip', 1521, 'sid'))
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e))
    print(e)
    traceback.print_tb(e.__traceback__)
```

P.S.
cx_Oracle - is very strange module.
It's try to get access to libs in:

```
/ade/b/3071542110/oracle/rdbms/lib/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
/ade/dosulliv_ldapmac/oracle/ldap/lib/libnnz11.dylib
```

I never have this paths but I created symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the actual install instructions for Instant Client: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html#ic_osx_inst
and create sym links in ~/lib for the Oracle libraries:

`ln -s libclntsh.dylib.11.1 libclntsh.dylib`

`mkdir ~/lib`

`ln -s /wherever/instantclient_11_2/{libclntsh.dylib.11.1,libnnz11.dylib,libociei.dylib} ~/lib/`

El Capitan broke DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, so there is no point setting it :(  And there is no point setting the Linux LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable either.

If you want to centralize the Instant Client installation see 5.3.1 in https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instosx

If you create a tnsnames.ora file, set TNS_ADMIN to the directory it is in.  Don't set ORACLE_HOME during runtime with Instant Client (although you might need it set temporarily during cx_Oracle installation.  Set it to the directory you unzipped Instant Client basic & sdk into, e.g. /Applications/oracle/instantclient_11_2)

Comment: Thank you very much! Step with symlink decided my problem!